# Vue 3 Loading script for svgPanZoom but the function is not defined

Tags: vuejs3

Following the instructions as stated in github for the project, but the following code is not working.  Getting Error = "Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: svgPanZoom is not defined"

Noted that in the network tab the appropriate script is loading.
Using this in a non-vue site and it's working as expected.

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Map',
  data() {
    return {
      
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$loadScript('https://unpkg.com/panzoom@9.4.0/dist/panzoom.min.js').then(() => {
      // Script is loaded, do something
       var element = document.getElementById('mapsvg');

  // and forward it it to panzoom.
  panzoom(element);
      //console.log('loaded.');
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

#mapsvg is a svg included in the template with that id.

I'm sure as a somewhat javascript newb i'm missing something obvious.  HALP PLZ :)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use the ready svgpanzoom module for vue.

> Install the package : npm i vue-svg-pan-zoom

To use:

```
<template>
   <SvgPanZoom 
     style="width: 500px; height: 500px; border:1px solid black;"
     :zoomEnabled="true"
     :controlIconsEnabled="true"
     :fit="false"
     :center="true"
     >
     <svg>
        <circle x="10" y="10" r="5" />
     </svg>
    </SvgPanZoom>`
 </template>

 <script>
   import SvgPanZoom from 'vue-svg-pan-zoom';
   export default {
     components: {  SvgPanZoom },
    };
 </script>
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-svg-pan-zoom

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work with vue3, do we know if it's compatible?

Answer (score 0):

Corrected by changing to correct function:

```
 var element = document.getElementById('mapsvg');

      // and forward it it to panzoom.
      panzoom(element);
```